# How to use retrace.bat to get the stack trace of obfuscated code in android

Tags: android

I am using `retrace.bat -verbose mapping.txt obfuscated_trace.txt` at the command prompt.

But it's showing the error message: `retrace.bat is not recognized as an internal command`.

How do I fix that error?

Comment: and what is your current directory in command prompt?

Comment: i am pointing to mapping.txt and include retrace.bat path in environmentvariables

Comment: can you try it from progaurd directory and give full path for your both .txt file?

Answer (score 4):

Please follow the below points.

1. open the terminal/cmd
2. cd **/sdk/tools/proguard/bin/proguardgui.jar
3. refer the attached image, retrace GUI pop's up
4. select your mapping file and copy-paste your obfuscated stacktrace

That's it. Simple and easy

[image]

Comment: this was helpful, however, the directory for this gui file is sdk/tools/proguard/lib/proguardgui.jar

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to write the .bat when you call retrace.bat, so write

```
retrace -verbose mapping.txt obfuscated_trace.txt
```

and maybe you are not in the current path, you should be at

```
...\android-sdk-windows\tools\proguard\bin
```

Answer (score 1):

If your current path at the command prompt is not the same as the bat file, and if the bat file path is not in your environment PATH, then you will get this error.

Either add the Android SDK Proguard bin path to your environment PATH, point to it directly during the call, or go to that path first:

`SET PATH=%PATH%;[path to Android SDK]\tools\proguard\bin`

(for example: `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\proguard\bin`)

Or to specify the path at the call:

`C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\proguard\bin\retrace.bat -verbose mapping.txt obfuscated_trace.txt`

Or go to the path first:

```
cd C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\proguard\bin\
retrace.bat -verbose "path\to\mapping.txt" "\path\to\obfuscated_trace.txt"
```